# How to write Asynchronous LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, asynchronous

After I read a bunch of LINQ related stuff, I suddenly realized that no articles introduce how to write asynchronous LINQ query.

Suppose we use LINQ to SQL, below statement is clear. However, if the SQL database responds slowly, then the thread using this block of code would be hindered.

```
var result = from item in Products where item.Price > 3 select item.Name;
foreach (var name in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Seems that current LINQ query spec doesn't provide support to this.

Is there any way to do asynchronous programming LINQ? It works like there is a callback 
notification when results are ready to use without any blocking delay on I/O.

Comment: Here is a interesting article: [LINQ to SQL: Asynchronously Executing Queries](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2007/12/06/10008.aspx) It's about using the ThreadPool and also using the [GetCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand.aspx) method of the DataContext

Comment: Did the answer below work out ok for you?

Comment: Check out the Reactive Extensions for .NET at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx, it's designed for asynchronous Linq queries.

Comment: Indeed, but not Linq *to SQL* queries which is what the author is asking about.

Comment: If you are looking for `async` - ready version of non - Linq-to-SQL `.Select` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25789815/477420.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

While LINQ doesn't really have this per se, the framework itself does...  You can easily roll your own asynchronous query executor in 30 lines or so...  In fact, I just threw this together for you :)

**EDIT: Through writing this, I've discovered why they didn't implement it.  It cannot handle anonymous types since they are scoped local.  Thus, you have no way of defining your callback function.**  This is a pretty major thing since a lot of linq to sql stuff creates them in the select clause.  Any of the below suggestions suffer the same fate, so I still think this one is the easiest to use!

EDIT: The only solution is to not use anonymous types.  You can declare the callback as just taking IEnumerable (no type args), and use reflection to access the fields (ICK!!).  Another way would be to declare the callback as "dynamic"...  oh... wait...  That's not out yet. :)  This is another decent example of how dynamic could be used.  Some may call it abuse.

Throw this in your utilities library:

```
public static class AsynchronousQueryExecutor
{
    public static void Call<T>(IEnumerable<T> query, Action<IEnumerable<T>> callback, Action<Exception> errorCallback)
    {
        Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>> func =
            new Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>>(InnerEnumerate<T>);
        IEnumerable<T> result = null;
        IAsyncResult ar = func.BeginInvoke(
                            query,
                            new AsyncCallback(delegate(IAsyncResult arr)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    result = ((Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>>)((AsyncResult)arr).AsyncDelegate).EndInvoke(arr);
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    if (errorCallback != null)
                                    {
                                        errorCallback(ex);
                                    }
                                    return;
                                }
                                //errors from inside here are the callbacks problem
                                //I think it would be confusing to report them
                                callback(result);
                            }),
                            null);
    }
    private static IEnumerable<T> InnerEnumerate<T>(IEnumerable<T> query)
    {
        foreach (var item in query) //the method hangs here while the query executes
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

And you could use it like this:

```
class Program
{

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //this could be your linq query
        var qry = TestSlowLoadingEnumerable();

        //We begin the call and give it our callback delegate
        //and a delegate to an error handler
        AsynchronousQueryExecutor.Call(qry, HandleResults, HandleError);

        Console.WriteLine("Call began on seperate thread, execution continued");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void HandleResults(IEnumerable<int> results)
    {
        //the results are available in here
        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    public static void HandleError(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error");
    }

    //just a sample lazy loading enumerable
    public static IEnumerable<int> TestSlowLoadingEnumerable()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        foreach (var i in new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 })
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }

}
```

Going to go put this up on my blog now, pretty handy.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to incorporate casting of some sort? Like this link: http://tomasp.net/articles/cannot-return-anonymous-type-from-method.aspx.

Comment: Effectively you are just passing the block to another thread in the threadpool? or is there some magic going on here?

Comment: This is a common mistake in .Net - applying the IAsync pattern on top of synchronous code instead of delegating to underlying asynchronous calls that leverage Windows I/O Completion Ports to hand the wait time off so it's not blocking any threads whatsoever. As Harry points out this hands the block off to another ThreadPool thread. This only has the minor benefit of the initiating thread being free to execute other side work. This approach risks blocking all ThreadPool threads if enough simultaneous requests come in that result in long queries.

Comment: I don't see anything adressing the Linq-to-sql specific problem (non thread safe connection)

Answer (score 16):

TheSoftwareJedi's and [ulrikb](http://ulrikb.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/executing-a-linq-query-asynchronously/)'s(aka user316318) solutions are good for any LINQ type, but (as pointed by  [Chris Moschini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176877/chris-moschini)) do NOT delegating to underlying asynchronous calls that leverage Windows I/O Completion Ports.

Wesley Bakker's [Asynchronous DataContext](http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2010/03/03/asynchronous-datacontext.aspx) post (triggered by [a blog post of Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode51AsynchronousDatabaseAccessAndLINQToSQLFun.aspx) ) describe class for LINQ to SQL that uses sqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader/sqlCommand.EndExecuteReader, which leverage Windows I/O Completion Ports.

[I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provide an efficient threading model for processing multiple asynchronous I/O requests on a multiprocessor system.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer, since it actually specifies how to do the operations in a proper asynchronous way that will benefit the program by not taking up a thread waiting for the operation to complete.

Answer (score 7):

Based on [Michael Freidgeim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6561839/186822) and mentioned [blog post from Scott Hansellman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode51AsynchronousDatabaseAccessAndLINQToSQLFun.aspx) and fact that you can use `async`/`await`, you can implement reusable `ExecuteAsync<T>(...)` method, which executes underlying `SqlCommand` asynchronously:

```
protected static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteAsync<T>(IQueryable<T> query,
    DataContext ctx,
    CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var cmd = (SqlCommand)ctx.GetCommand(query);

    if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        await cmd.Connection.OpenAsync(token);
    var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(token);

    return ctx.Translate<T>(reader);
}
```

And then you can (re)use it like this:

```
public async Task WriteNamesToConsoleAsync(string connectionString, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
{
    using (var ctx = new DataContext(connectionString))
    {
        var query = from item in Products where item.Price > 3 select item.Name;
        var result = await ExecuteAsync(query, ctx, token);
        foreach (var name in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution so far for querying the objects, it covers most of scenarios and it's pretty neat. But is there any way to achieve an async SubmitChanges? For example, in order to insert a new record to a table.

Answer (score 4):

I started a simple github project named [Asynq](https://github.com/JamesDunne/Asynq/) to do asynchronous LINQ-to-SQL query execution. The idea is quite simple albeit "brittle" at this stage (as of 8/16/2011):

1. Let LINQ-to-SQL do the "heavy" work of translating your `IQueryable` into a `DbCommand` via the `DataContext.GetCommand()`.
2. For SQL 200[058], cast up from the abstract `DbCommand` instance you got from `GetCommand()` to get a `SqlCommand`. If you're using SQL CE you're out of luck since `SqlCeCommand` does not expose the async pattern for `BeginExecuteReader` and `EndExecuteReader`.
3. Use `BeginExecuteReader` and `EndExecuteReader` off the `SqlCommand` using the standard .NET framework asynchronous I/O pattern to get yourself a `DbDataReader` in the completion callback delegate that you pass to the `BeginExecuteReader` method.
4. Now we have a `DbDataReader` which we have no idea what columns it contains nor how to map those values back up to the `IQueryable`'s `ElementType` (most likely to be an anonymous type in the case of joins). Sure, at this point you could hand-write your own column mapper that materializes its results back into your anonymous type or whatever. You'd have to write a new one per each query result type, depending on how LINQ-to-SQL treats your IQueryable and what SQL code it generates. This is a pretty nasty option and I don't recommend it since it's not maintainable nor would it be always correct. LINQ-to-SQL can change your query form depending on the parameter values you pass in, for example `query.Take(10).Skip(0)` produces different SQL than `query.Take(10).Skip(10)`, and perhaps a different resultset schema. Your best bet is to handle this materialization problem programmatically:
5. "Re-implement" a simplistic runtime object materializer that pulls columns off the `DbDataReader` in a defined order according to the LINQ-to-SQL mapping attributes of the `ElementType` Type for the `IQueryable`. Implementing this correctly is probably the most challenging part of this solution.

As others have discovered, the `DataContext.Translate()` method does not handle anonymous types and can only map a `DbDataReader` directly to a properly attributed LINQ-to-SQL proxy object. Since most queries worth writing in LINQ are going to involve complex joins which inevitably end up requiring anonymous types for the final select clause, it's pretty pointless to use this provided watered-down `DataContext.Translate()` method anyway.

There are a few minor drawbacks to this solution when leveraging the existing mature LINQ-to-SQL IQueryable provider:

1. You cannot map a single object instance to multiple anonymous type properties in the final select clause of your `IQueryable`, e.g. `from x in db.Table1 select new { a = x, b = x }`. LINQ-to-SQL internally keeps track of which column ordinals map to which properties; it does not expose this information to the end user so you have no idea which columns in the `DbDataReader` are reused and which are "distinct".
2. You cannot include constant values in your final select clause - these do not get translated into SQL and will be absent from the `DbDataReader` so you'd have to build custom logic to pull these constant values up from the `IQueryable`'s `Expression` tree, which would be quite a hassle and is simply not justifiable.

I'm sure there are other query patterns that might break but these are the two biggest I could think of that could cause problems in an existing LINQ-to-SQL data access layer.

These problems are easy to defeat - simply don't do them in your queries since neither pattern provides any benefit to the end result of the query. Hopefully this advice applies to all query patterns that would potentially cause object materialization problems :-P. It's a hard problem to solve not having access to LINQ-to-SQL's column mapping information.

A more "complete" approach to solving the problem would be to effectively re-implement nearly all of LINQ-to-SQL, which is a bit more time-consuming :-P. Starting from a quality, open-source LINQ-to-SQL provider implementation would be a good way to go here. The reason you'd need to reimplement it is so that you'd have access to all of the column mapping information used to materialize the `DbDataReader` results back up to an object instance without any loss of information.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this github project is VERY MUCH a WORK IN PROGRESS. I ACTIVELY DISCOURAGE you from using it in ANY production code whatsoever. It's a simple research project at this stage used to demonstrate the idea that it can be done.

Comment: A code example with a similar solution. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode51AsynchronousDatabaseAccessAndLINQToSQLFun.aspx