# Call a Stored Procedure asynchronously using LINQ to SQL

Tags: .net, sql, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write Asynchronous LINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252355/how-to-write-asynchronous-linq-query)

How can i call a Stored Procedure asynchronously using linq to sql.

Comment: why -1? it is a perfectly valid question, i looked a lot trying to find an answer before i posted it here

Comment: I like this question, I might try to figure out an answer if I get the time.

Comment: You could maybe try to use a normal SQL async call and then populate your object by calling the Translate method of the context?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a look.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386946.aspx

Comment: found something here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b6f9k7k.aspx