# Match 2 property of any object in local list using Linq

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

```
    public class OrderItem
    {
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public int ProductionID { get; set; }
    }

    public class InventoryItem
    {
        public int InventoryItemID{ get; set; }
        public int OrderID { get; set; }
        public int ProductionID { get; set; }
        public bool Created { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    }
```

Using these example objects,

I have a local list of orderItems and want  to query inventory items where OrderID and ProductionID matches on both properties any of my list of Order Items

I tried linq query below but I am getting an error

Query I am trying:

```
    var results = await db.InventoryItems.Where(d =>
                  listOfOrderItems.Any(o => o.OrderID == d.OrderID && !d.DeleteFlag && d.ProductionId == o.ProductionItemId))
                  .Select(t => t.InventoryItemID).ToListAsync();
```

> Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

EDIT
i am being referred to this question:[Using Linq to Sql asynchronously with new async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498564/using-linq-to-sql-asynchronously-with-new-async-await)

But my question is not about async await, it is about the matching 2 properties using the .any on my list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Linq to Sql asynchronously with new async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498564/using-linq-to-sql-asynchronously-with-new-async-await)

Comment: No, my question is not about async await, it is about the matching 2 properties using the .any on my list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking further into the error I found this error:

> Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

My collection listOfOrderItems was of type List, changing it to IEnumerable fixed my problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var localIdPairs = listOfOrderItems.Select(x => x.OrderId + "-" + x.ProductionItemId).ToList();

var results = await db.InventoryItems
          .Where(d => !d.DeleteFlag && 
                      localIdPairs.Contains(d.OrderId + "-" + d.ProductionItemId))
          .Select(t => t.InventoryItemID).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This won't work because I need it to match on both properties from the same object

Comment: Nice :) Love the creativity! It might actually work but feels like a hack to me, just wondering if there's a more official way