# How to add an async "await" to an addrange select statement?

Tags: c#, .net, select, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have a function like this:

```
public async Task<SomeViewModel> SampleFunction()
{
    var data = service.GetData();
    var myList = new List<SomeViewModel>();

    myList.AddRange(data.select(x => new SomeViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        DateCreated = x.DateCreated,
        Data = await service.GetSomeDataById(x.Id)
    }

    return myList;
}
```

My `await` isn't working as it can only be used in a method or lambda marked with the `async` modifier.  Where do I place the `async` with this function?

Comment: It's unlikely you can do this directly, because `Enumerable.Select()` is not an async method.

Comment: service.GetSomeDataByID is probably defined something like `public object GetSomeDataByID(int Id)` If it's not defined with the async keyword you cannot use await to call it. It would need to be defined as `public async object GetSomeDataByID(int Id)`

Comment: It is defined 'public async Task<string> GetSomeDataById(int Id)' which works everywhere else.  Just not inside this AddRange Select statement

Comment: @Nick You can't `await` an `object`. It would need to be `Task<object>`. However, Selman22 has given the correct answer anyway.

Comment: @DanielKelley Why are you taking it so literally? GetSomeDataByID is not defined here and there is absolutely nothing in the question that indicates what the return type of GetSomeDataById is. I was using object as a placeholder for whatever the return type actually is.

Comment: @Nick Because those who are asking a question gain more knowledge from technically correct answers, as opposed to vague ones.

Comment: @DanielKelley Vague questions receive vague answers. People can't be expect to psychically determine what types are being used when the code provided declares everything as "var" from functions whose names do not even imply a certain return type.

Answer (score 13):

You can only use `await` inside an `async` method/delegate. In this case you must mark that lambda expression as `async`.

But wait, there's more...

`Select` is from the pre-`async` era and so it doesn't handle `async` lambdas (in your case it would return `IEnumerable<Task<SomeViewModel>>` instead of `IEnumerable<SomeViewModel>` which is what you actually need).

You can however add that functionality yourself (preferably as an extension method), but you need to consider whether you wish to `await` each item before moving on to the next (sequentialy) or `await` all items together at the end (concurrently).

### Sequential `async`

```
static async Task<TResult[]> SelectAsync<TItem, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TItem> enumerable, Func<TItem, Task<TResult>> selector)
{
    var results = new List<TResult>();
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        results.Add(await selector(item));
    }
    return results.ToArray();
}
```

### Concurrent `async`

```
static Task<TResult[]> SelectAsync<TItem, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TItem> enumerable, Func<TItem, Task<TResult>> selector)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(enumerable.Select(selector));
}
```

### Usage

```
public Task<SomeViewModel[]> SampleFunction()
{
    return service.GetData().SelectAsync(async x => new SomeViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        DateCreated = x.DateCreated,
        Data = await service.GetSomeDataById(x.Id)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're using `await` inside of a lambda, and that lambda is going to be transformed into its own separate named method by the compiler.  To use `await` it must itself be `async`, and not just be defined in an `async` method.  When you make the lambda `async` you now have a sequence of tasks that you want to translate into a sequence of their results, asynchronously.  `Task.WhenAll` does exactly this, so we can pass our new query to `WhenAll` to get a task representing our results, which is exactly what this method wants to return:

```
public Task<SomeViewModel[]> SampleFunction()
{
    return Task.WhenAll(service.GetData().Select(
        async x => new SomeViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        DateCreated = x.DateCreated,
        Data = await service.GetSomeDataById(x.Id)
    }));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Though maybe too heavyweight for your use case, using TPL Dataflow will give you finer control over your async processing.

```
public async Task<List<SomeViewModel>> SampleFunction()
{
    var data = service.GetData();

    var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<X, SomeViewModel>(
        async x => new SomeViewModel
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            DateCreated = x.DateCreated,
            Data = await service.GetSomeDataById(x.Id)
        },
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
        {
            // Let 8 "service.GetSomeDataById" calls run at once.
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 8
        });

    var result = new List<SomeViewModel>();

    var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<SomeViewModel>(
        vm => result.Add(vm));

    transformBlock.LinkTo(actionBlock,
        new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

    foreach (var x in data)
    {
        transformBlock.Post(x);
    }
    transformBlock.Complete();

    await actionBlock.Completion;

    return result;
}
```

This could be substantially less long-winded if `service.GetData()` returned an `IObservable<X>` and this method returned an `IObservable<SomeViewModel>`.

Comment: All that you're using the TPL dataflow here is to take a sequence of tasks and create a task representing the sequence of the results.  You can do this all with a single method call, `Task.WhenAll`, as seen in my answer.

Comment: @Servy It's doing slightly more than that. The "finer control" is in the specification of the `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions` on the `TransformBlock`. For example, if you're hitting a web service (via `service.GetSomeDataById`) that can handle 8 concurrent requests just as quickly as 1, this will run 8 times faster. Your implementation is properly async, but it still performs the calls to `service.GetSomeDataById` serially.

Comment: @Servy My last paragraph was also alluding to the code becoming drastically shorter if you use `IObservable<T>` for your "async-computed collections" rather than `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T>`. :) If I were to do this, I'd probably refactor the method to operate that way.

Comment: The code in my answer isn't serial, it is doing the queries in parallel.

Comment: @Servy Oh you're right. It's not rate-limited though, which admittedly is probably not an issue in this case.