# LINQ select new Async/Await

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asynchronous, async-await

I currently have a asynchronous query as follows which is fine and allows me to use the FirstOrDefaultAsync / ToListAsync methods.

```
 public async Task<X> FindXAsync(int x)
 {
      var q = from c in context.X
              where c.Id == x
              select c;

      return await q.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
 }
```

However I am attempting to extend that query to select into a new class

```
public async Task<XClass> FindXAsync(int x)
{
     var q = from c in context.X
            where c.Id == x
            select new XClass (
            c.Id,c.Header .........
            );

     return await q.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

For the above you can no longer use the FirstOrDefaultAsync() only FirstOrDefault(), I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to get this functionality into an asynchronous method.
Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Why not use `context.X.FirstOrDefaultAsync(y=>y.Id == x);`?

Comment: @MihailStancescu because he want to project the result with select

Comment: Ok you are right. I thought that XClass is the same as `context.X`.

Comment: But your syntax inside select seems wrong you wrote "new class XClass{c.Id.." But should be "new class {Id=c.Id.."

Comment: @tede24 xClass has a constructor that takes in those as parameters

Comment: @Chris You should not be using the class constructor for EF query projection

Comment: You can't use class Initialization there as part of linq to entities. Do you really need it? Why?

Comment: Anonymous async is not supported 
Take a look this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/252426/1876572

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the easiest answer is probably just to do the (asynchronous) first selection, and *then* create the type you need:

```
public async Task<XClass> FindXAsync(int x)
{
  var q = from c in context.X
          where c.Id == x
          select c;
  var c = await q.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
  return new XClass (
           c.Id,c.Header .........
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, realized the problem after reading the comments but thanks for the answer. p.s. Concurrency In C# Cookbook was an excellent reference book for starting to work with asynchronous programming.

Comment: On a side note how would this work with the result of a stored procedure as the result is an IEnumerable ?

Comment: @Chris: I don't have much experience with sprocs, but I believe it should work fine; it would be exposed as an IQueryable over the network and I'd expect EF's `FirstOrDefaultAsync` to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with generic typed parameter:

```
return await q.FirstOrDefaultAsync<XClass>();
```

Comment: q does not contain a definition for FirstOrDefaultAsync

Comment: Add reference to `System.Data.Entity` from EntittyFramework.

Comment: Additionally you need to use the parameterless constructor for `XClass`. ie `new XClass { Id = c.Id, ...}`  rather than `new XClass(c.Id,...)`